# extends and block not working in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm learning how to use Django templates but I cant get extends and block to work.

Here is my code.

template.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <body>
         {% block theTitle %}
         {% endblock %}
       </body>
   </html>
```

textComponent.html

```
{% extends 'templates/template.html' %} {% block theTitle %}
<div>what is going on?</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is how the files are organised:

_templates

__template.html

__textComponent.html

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance), how about just:

```
{% extends "template.html" %} 
{% block theTitle %}
    <div>what is going on?</div>
{% endblock %}
```

According to the [extends tag documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#extends):

```
Normally the template name is relative to the template loader’s root directory.
```

So, you are probably looking for your template.html file inside:

```
templates/templates/template.html
```

Which is the wrong path.